# JavaScript filter returning true but not filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

For the past hour I've been struggling to get this following code to work:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < weekarr.length; i++) {
    if (i - 1 > -1) {
      weekarr[i].forEach(arr => {
        weekarr[i - 1].forEach(p => {
          if (
            arr.html === p.html &&
            !(arr.category === "prehab" && arr.canDo === true)
          ) {
            weekarr[i].filter(p => {
              console.log(p === arr);
              return p === arr;
            });
            // if (i + 1 < 5) weekarr[i + 1].push(arr);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

weekarr looks like this:

[image: weekarr]

I am basically trying to remove an array item if the previous array contains the same array item (in this case recognized with the html property). Everything works perfectly, except it is simply not filtering. I console logged whether it is returning true or false values when it is supposed to, and it is. Can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: @Pavitra `filter` is being used inside the second `forEach` :)

Comment: @SerShubham Noticed after posting my comment :)

Comment: You’re not doing anything with the filtered array. It filters then you ignore it and move on.

Comment: Oh man, too much coding for one day. Can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter function returns a new array. It does not modify the original array.
Try storing the result of your filter in a new variable and return that?

```
const filteredWeakArr = weekarr[i].filter(p => {
   console.log(p === arr);
   return p === arr;
});
```

Now, `filteredWeakArr` should have your desired result

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are not saving the filter array. The result should be saved to be effective e.g.

```
weekarr[i] = weekarr[i].filter(p => {
          console.log(p === arr);
          return p === arr;
});
```

Also check [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more info